# what is the diff between save_model and save_formset in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am reading the `save_model` and `save_formset` in django admin from here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

But I am confused as to when `save_formset` is called.

Shouldn't the formset be saved during `save_model`?

Answer (score 22):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/) could use a little clarification.

- `save_model` is called during add or change to save the base model. It is specifically *not* intended to save related or inlined models.
- `save_related` is called (once) after `save_model` completes to save off all related / inlined models.
- `save_formset` is called potentially many times during each add / change, once for every inline defined on your `ModelAdmin`. It is called by the base class implementation of `save_related`.

If you look at the code for `admin.ModelAdmin`, you can see that `save_model` and `save_related` happen one after the other:

```
class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(...):
        # ...
        if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated:
            self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
            self.save_related(request, form, formsets, not add)
```

and that `save_related` has a simple implementation to call `save_formset` for each inline:

```
class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
    # ...
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        form.save_m2m()
        for formset in formsets:
            self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=change)
```

Answer (score 3):

`save_model` saves main model
`save_related` saves `ManyToMany` and calls `save_formset` for each particular inline

Answer (score 1):

save_model is for the model being edited i.e. whatever model you registered your ModelAdmin with

save_formset is for saving the formsets (ModelAdmin.inlines)

Comment: then what is `ModelAdmin.save_related` used for

Comment: The save_related method is given the HttpRequest, the parent ModelForm instance, the list of inline formsets and a boolean value based on whether the parent is being added or changed. Here you can do any pre- or post-save operations for objects related to the parent. Note that at this point the parent object and its form have already been saved.

Comment: The save_model method is given the HttpRequest, a model instance, a ModelForm instance and a boolean value based on whether it is adding or changing the object. Here you can do any pre- or post-save operations. The save_formset method is given the HttpRequest, the parent ModelForm instance and a boolean value based on whether it is adding or changing the parent object.

Comment: they both look same to me as per you comment